# drop down list has lots of items in the list, can I share this list with multiple drown downs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a page with the same drop down list in 3 or so places on the page.

The dropdowns have many items in the list, I was wondering if I could just load the drop down lists form a single source instead of having to repeat it so many times on the same (since its the exact same select options for all the drop downs).

Is this possible with jquery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. Say your source dropdown has ID `source` and the destination dropdowns have class `dest`. Then this will work:

```
$(function ()
{
    $('select.dest').html($('#source > option').clone());
});
```

Comment: But will this still have 3 or whatever instaces of the same data then? I'm trying to keep the DOM size down by referencing a single instance of the option list.

Comment: You can't just use a "pointer," if that's what you mean. HTML does not support that sort of thing.

Comment: @Blankman: unless you're looking at **thousands** of DOM elements, DOM size is **not** a relevant issue.

Comment: well if you're using IE6 having too many dropdowns kills the performance of the page, even to the point of scrolling being a problem.  Only need around 100 to see it.  (company finally gets off iE6 this month... can't wait)

Comment: "If you're using IE6" is not a valid argument in my book, ever. Screw IE6.

Answer (score 1):

```
<select id="list1">
 <option>One</option>
 <option>One</option>
 <option>One</option>
</select>

<select id="list2"></select>

<select id="list3"></select>


$(function() {
  var options = $("#list1 option");
  $("#list2").html(options.clone());
  $("#list3").html(options.clone());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can append the same options to multiple select lists:

```
<select id="mySelect"></select>
<select id="list2"></select>
<select id="list3"></select>

var myOptions = {
    val1 : 'text1',
    val2 : 'text2',
    val3 : 'text3'
};

$.each(myOptions, function(val, text) {
    $('#mySelect').append(
        $('<option></option>').val(val).html(text)
    );
    $('#list2').append(
        $('<option></option>').val(val).html(text)
    );
    $('#list3').append(
        $('<option></option>').val(val).html(text)
    );
});
```

**Working Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/P2Xqd/

Answer (score 0):

Three dropdowns can't really share the same list of options without copying them.  The only way you would be able to do this would be through the creation of some sort of custom dropdown.

For instance when you click on this custom dropdown (not a true dropdown), the actual dropdown is re-positioned over the custom dropdown you clicked on and expanded.  Then when the option is selected the selected value is copied into your custom dropdown.  This custom dropdown would then need a hidden input to hold the selected value to be passed along with the form.